# What is the best Library/SDK for Realtime 4k video Encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, video-encoding, libavcodec

My requirement is create a encoded video from raw frames in atleast 4k resolution. Presently I am recording videos @1080p using libavcodec (H.264, MPEG4). What will be the best solution for recording these videos @4k?

Is it possible to do multithreaded encoding using libavcodec?
Another option could be using Intel QuickSync. How good is that?

are there other any solutions available?

Edit: I require atleast 24FPS.

Answer (score 3):

Best is very subjective. You can get faster encoding with lower quality and somebody maybe fine with that. You did not mention your codecs in use. AFAIK, libavcodec with x264 can handle 4k resolution with multiple threads. The hardware will become the limiting factor I think.  My i7 manages 4 fps with medium preset main profile and 8 threads running in parallel which goes upto 8 fps for baseline profile. So still some way to go. If you have quad processor system x264 should still be able to do it.

Never used Intel QuickSync so cannot comment there.

A pointer: CUDA based encoding might be faster if that is an option for you.

Comment: okay ! thats very bad I require atleast 24 fps. I am using MPEG4 as of now. 
Thanks for the information anyways. I want to do it on CPU only i f that is not an option then I will go for GPGPU.